# file_put_contents and a new line help

Tags: php

I've got a file that I'm writing to and I cannot get file_put_contents to append the next entry on a new line, even after a newline character. What am I missing? I'm on a windows machine.

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$message = "test\n\n";
file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

how are you viewing the contents of `$file`? if you're using notepad you can't see `\n`.

Comment: Yes, in notepad.. Ok, so this is my problem then? Is there something that I can do to see the breaks in notepad?

Comment: i use notepad2. download at www.flos-freeware.ch

Comment: Volker, thanks. Also to you RockJock. That did the trick. I was doing \n\r which I guess makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks rockjock. going there now.

Answer (score 122):

try

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$message = "test".PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

or

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$message = "test\r\n";
file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: @Gordon -1 for using `PHP_EOL`! This constant is only useful if you use a file for internal purposes and is massively overused. In most cases, UNIX-friendly `\n` is a better choice.

Comment: @RoboRobok question was about `\n` not working on a windows machine, `PHP_EOL` or `\r\n` seems very appropriate here. this is not about "most cases"

Answer (score 32):

For the PHP_EOL you may not be seeing your new line because you are defining the end of the line after you write your new line. Therefore the new line is only made after the new content is added to the last line of your text file.

it should read like this:

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$message = 'some message that should appear on the last line of test.txt';
file_put_contents($file, PHP_EOL . $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: This answer needs WAY more love. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just give a normal new line and it works

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$message = "test
";
file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are passing the second argument to file_put_contents as an array rather than a string, it also works to put PHP_EOL as the last array element:

```
file_put_contents($file, array('value 1', 'value 2', PHP_EOL), FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, read something about the **new line** character. It is different for each operating system... There is *LF*, *CR*, *CR+LF*... Have a look [***here***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

On Windows, you need *CR+LF* (`\r\n`) as Mathieu already said.
On Linux, only *LF* is needed (`\n`)

But, to be sure, use `PHP_EOL`.

In using files, you would probably need to know more about path and directory separators. They are also different. Use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of forward-slash or back-slash ;)