# Doesn't write properly on new line in file

Tags: php

So I have simple registration form that write user and password in file.txt. 
When 1 line in the file has already user and password every next registration is on same line and in the same time put empty next line.

If the file is empty is writing properly, every registration is on new line.
Here is the code that i use:

```
        if(!$error) {
        $input = $username . '|' . $pass ."\n";
        file_put_contents('users/file.txt', $input, FILE_APPEND);

        mkdir('users/'. $username);

        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
```

p.s. I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325241/file-put-contents-and-a-new-line-help

Comment: Possible solution: `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: I tried and is the same. I don't understand why is this. If the file has already first line and empty second line is write properly. But if is only first line will write on the first?

Comment: Are you on Windows and trying to open the file.txt in Notepad?

Comment: Yes, I'm on localhost with windows. And I use Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this will be good for You:

```
if(!$error) {
    if (strlen(file_get_contents('users/file.txt')) > 1){
        $input = "\n" . $username . '|' . $pass;
    } else {
        $input = $username . '|' . $pass;
    }

        file_put_contents('users/file.txt', $input, FILE_APPEND);

        mkdir('users/'. $username);

        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
if(!$error) {  
$input = $username . '|' . $pass ."\n";  
$fh = fopen("users/file.txt", 'a') or die("can't open file");  
fwrite($fh, $input);  
fclose($fh);  

header('Location: index.php');  
exit;  
}
```

Comment: If there is no empty second line in file is writing on the same line. This happen only if i have already one line and no second empty after first.

Comment: I guess I will save the file with empty second line. I can't find other solution.