# file_put_contents() and newline characters \n

Tags: php, markdown

"[file_put_contents and a new line help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325241/file-put-contents-and-a-new-line-help)" is close but does not help with my issue.

A user fills in a textarea, which is then sent to a php page for processing.

```
<form id="slidetext" method="POST" action="create-process.php">
<textarea cols="100" rows="20" id="text" name="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The user's input is then used to create a new markdown file on the server.

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$file = "files/example.md";
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

This works and appears to create a file that adheres to the rules for data separation within the reveal.js framework:

```
<div class="reveal">
        <div class="slides">
            <section data-markdown="files/example.md"  
                data-separator="^\n\n\n"  
                data-vertical="^\n\n"  
                data-notes="^Note:"  
                data-charset="iso-8859-15">
            </section>      
        </div>
</div>
```

Despite the example.md file looking like it has new line breaks in the right places, it does not display properly.

If I write the same file manually it does however display as expected. Any help appreciated.

Comment: An example of how it fails would help.

Comment: have you tried `\r\n`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255511/php-echo-line-breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\r\n` (Windows linebreaks) instead of `\n` (Unix linebreaks) might fix this.